# How to have default parameter for routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is my route definitions:

```
export default <Route>
    <Route path='account/login' component={Login}/>
    <Route component={ Layout }>
        <Route path='/' components={{ body: Home, bar: NavBar }} />
        <Route path='/entry' components={{ body: Entry, bar: NavBar }}>
            <Route path='(:weekStartDate)'/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Route>;
```

All I want to achieve is if the users goes to "mysite.com/entry", he should be redirected to "mysite.com/entry/12-09-2016". Why does this have to be so hard? I could not find any resources to achieve this. Can you please help me fix the problem?

react version: 15.0.1
react-router version: 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem several months ago. The only suitable solution, that I found, is a server-side redirect.

Comment: This should not be the way. This is really frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

Use an onEnter function for the route that checks if the param is set and defaults it otherwise.

```
function defaultParam(nextState, replace) {
  if (!nextState.params.weekStartDate) {
    replace('/entry/12-09-2016')
  }
}

...
<Route path='entry/:weekStartDate' onEnter={defaultParam} components={{ body: Entry, bar: NavBar }}/>
```

[`onEnter` Documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback)